# Getting error while sending Outlook email using Python

Tags: python-3.x, email, outlook, test-runner

Here is the code which I found in internet and modified according to my need:

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'W57007'
mail.Subject = 'Message subject'
mail.Body = 'Message body'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h2>HTML Message body</h2>' #this field is optional

# To attach a file to the email (optional):
# attachment  = "Path to the attachment"
# mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)

mail.Send()
```

When this is run, I get below error:

mail.Send()

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467260, 'Operation aborted', None, None)
```

Please help me mitigate this error. Any further details needed, please let me know!

[image]

Comment: The ```newMail.Send``` works without the parenthesis.
Also the ```newMail.Display()``` functions well.

Comment: Does mail.Recipients.ResolveAll() return true?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: I commented out the newMail.Send() and added newMail.Recipients.ResolveAll(). Still the same error :(

Comment: Yes, but what does ResolveAll return? Does it raise an exception?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The issue was that I had deleted a directory with the pst file inside